# PHP7 FPM Refusing to Start

Tags: server, php, php7, php-fpm

I keep receiving an error on my Ubuntu 16.04 server with PHP 7 FPM

```
ERROR: fork() failed: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
```

Which results in none of my sites working with a 502 error.

NOTE: I am using the ondrej repo for php7, and have the following modules installed (if it helps any....)

```
php7.0-fpm php7.0-cli php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-intl php7.0-mysql php7.0-json php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-opcache php-memcached php-pear
```

And utilize nGinx

How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks like it might be relevant http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274830/880 but I'm in no position to test. See if it helps and if it does, use it to write an answer here to help other people in the same sitch :)

Comment: Aye mate, tried that yesterday :)   got an error tho... invalid `unlimited`, but I used a really high number and same situation, same error message :)

Comment: I almost hate saying this... because ondrej in a genius... but I will post in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve my issues, I needed to purge php7 from my server, remove the ondrej repo, and install everything from the Ubuntu repos.

**My Steps:**

```
apt-get --purge remove php7*
rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej*
apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade #just for safeties sake
apt-get -y install php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-intl php7.0-mysql php7.0-json php7.0-sqlite3 php7.0-opcache php-memcached php-pear
```

And now all is well.

Comment: This is strange. I am guessing this might be some upstream PHP problem, as I think there were any changes between what Ubuntu has and my repos has apart from 7.0.4 vs 7.0.5

Comment: I would be glad if you could retry with 7.0.6 later today (I am in process of updating PPA to new PHP releases right now).

Comment: I'm honored mate, that you are commenting on one of my questions! :D :D  Big time!   I will certainly try later on

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with PHP-FPM seemingly "stuck" around 500 child processes and not being able to fork more because of the error "Resource temporarily unavailable".

Based on a comment above from Oli, I looked into https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274830/880

This was the fix for me, related to the default task limit that systemd puts in place (in my case it was 512). I ran "systemctl edit php-fpm", added the following lines:

```
[Service]
TasksMax=infinity
```

Then ran `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart php-fpm`.